# How to extract pair values from dataframe with condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
id   1    2    3    5
1    1   0.6  0.2  0.9
2   0.6  1    0.4  0.8
3   0.2  0.4  1    0.2
5   0.9  0.8  0.2  1
```

columns are id, 1, 2, 3, 5. I want to extract pairs of value from column id and other columns with values higher than 0.7. So desired result is:

```
id1     id2     value
 1       5      0.9
 2       5      0.8
```

How to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: seems to be a symmetric matrix, do you want the row-column name of only the upper half?

Comment: @enke what do you mean by upper-half? i want the output be in format that i described. yeah its symmetric). but its pandas dataframe

Comment: @enke i updated output format, i think this way it maybe easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `numpy.triu` + `where` +`stack`:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.set_index('id')
out = df.where(np.triu(df.to_numpy()>0.7, k=1)).stack()\
        .rename_axis(['id1','id2']).reset_index(name='value')
```

Output:

```
   id1 id2  value
0    1   5    0.9
1    2   5    0.8
```